# Doctrine: data too long for column (due to escaping)

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I got the following error:

The 'name' column is 255 characters long, but it seems that output escaping messes it up. What did I do wrong?

> An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO parts (deletedAt,
>   name, code, price, in_stock) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' with params
>   [null,
>   "\x50\x6f\x73\x74\x4e\x4c\x20\x50\x72\x69\x6f\x72\x69\x74\x79\x20\x50\x61\x6b\x6b\x65\x74\x20\x41\x61\x6e\x67\x65\x74\x65\x6b\x65\x6e\x64\x20\x42\x65\x6c\x67\x69\xeb",
>   "1101012", "12.00", 0]:
>
> SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for
>   column 'name' at row 1 500 Internal Server Error - DriverException 2
>   linked Exceptions:
>   PDOException » PDOException »

```
        foreach ($csv as $row) { #persist every part
            $part = new Part();
            $part->setCode($row[0]);
            $part->setName($row[1]);
            $part->setPrice(preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/","", $row[2])); # extract decimal number
            $part->setInStock(($row[3])?1:0);

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($part);
            $count++; # get number of commits
        }

        $em->flush();
```

from my my.ini:

```
[client]
port = 3306
socket = /tmp/mysql.sock
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[mysql]
default-character-set = utf8mb4
no-auto-rehash

[mysqld]
port = 3306
collation-server        = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
init-connect            = 'SET NAMES utf8mb4'
character-set-server    = utf8mb4
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

Comment: What do you mean by output escaping? This is a Symfony message; can you show the controller code just before you do the em->flush() ? In particular what you do for `name`!!!! That's the one with all those escape codes.

Comment: If you are really trying to persist data greater than 255 chars (which seems unlikely given your error message) then increase the column size.

Comment: added the requested code. It works if I truncate the string to about 5 characters, but that's obviously not what I want.

Comment: Why don't you change type of 'name' property in your corresponding entity from string to text? http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types

Comment: hi @pavlovich it's actually overkill because my string will never be longer than 255 characters. But I did change it to 'text' now, regenerated entities, dropped and rebuilt the database, but it still says data too long.

SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'name' at row 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turned out there were two problems.

One was that Doctrine did not respect the default collation set by the MySQL server, and even a myriad of options in config.yml etc. Finally I have it looking like this, and I don't really understand why. But it works now.

```
charset:  utf8mb4
default_table_options:
    charset: utf8mb4
    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
options:
    charset: utf8mb4
    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    1002: "SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'"
```

Second was that the source of the data I was trying to load into the database (a csv file) was apparently not in utf8. Saving it into "utf8" solved the problem. Now I wonder how I can make php convert the input into the desired format.